# Notification pop-up on desktop from web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I need to be able to show notification popups in the bottom right hand corner of the desktop, not the bottom right hand corner of the browser window like something like toastr can, needs to be the desktop bottom right hand corner. I have seen it done I think but can't recall where.

Anybody got any ideas?

I'm guessing javascript/jquery?

Comment: Gmail does something like that, if this is what you are refering to

Comment: Yes but don't you need notifications enabled? I admit I haven't tried it but I am looking more for how it is achieved code wise thanks

Comment: If Gmail-like popups is what you are looking for, please [edit] your question to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for notification() which can do that given the user gives the website permission to use it.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

**from linked DOCS:**

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>

function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```